# Can I set value of an object by accessing other values in this object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am new in React.js, I am designing a little game.

When I am setting the `life` value, I want to use the value of `job`, can I do it in React.js?

Here is part of my code:

```
this.setState({
            players:[
                {
                    id:uuid.v4(),
                    name: "A",
                    job: "Wizard",
                    life: this.getRandHealth("Wizard")
                }, {
                    id:uuid.v4(),
                    name: "B",
                    job: "Witch",
                    life: this.getRandHealth("Witch")
                }]});
```

I want directly access `job` instead of signing them manually. Can I do it?

Comment: When will the code above be called? If `this.getRandHealth` will update the health as well, you don't have to list the other parameters, but just change life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to define the players list without the `life` and then use `.map()` to add it:

```
var list = [{
  id: uuid.v4(),
  name: "A",
  job: "Wizard",
}, {
  id: uuid.v4(),
  name: "B",
  job: "Witch",
}];

this.setState({
  players: list.map(function(obj) {
    return {
      id: obj.id,
      name: obj.name,
      job: obj.job,
      life: this.getRandHealth(obj.job)
    };
  }, this);
});
```

If the id is always `uuid.v4()` then you can move that into the map as well and reduce the repetition further.

Comment: It seems the generated state will be refreshed after I submit a form, could you please look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545184/react-js-initial-state-generated-randomly-how-to-prevent-it-from-regenerate-e