# (React.js)Why react cannot find the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am a newbie learning to build a rpg game with React.js, and I found this part very confusing.

I am trying to update `life` with `onClick` and when `life`<`damage`, the `object` `player` is dropped. So the html looks like this:

[image]

The current player is generated like this:

```
<h4>You are: {this.props.targets[this.props.playerindex].name}</h4>
```

I use these code to handle attack and update the index:

```
handleAttack(index1,id2){
    let players = this.state.players.slice();
    let index2 = players.findIndex(x => x.id === id2);
    let damage = players[index1].damage;
    let life = players[index2].life;
    console.log("Before(length):"+this.state.players.length);
    if (life>damage){
        players[index2].life = life-damage;}
    else {players=players.filter(player => player.id !== id2);}
    this.setState({players},()=>{console.log("After(length):"+this.state.players.length);
                                 this.handleUpdateIndex();});
}

handleUpdateIndex(){
    console.log("Before:"+this.state.playerindex);
    let index=this.state.playerindex;
    let length=this.state.players.length;
    console.log("BeforeUpdate(length)"+this.state.players.length);
    if(index<length-1)
    {this.setState({playerindex:index+1},() => {console.log("After:"+this.state.playerindex);});}
    else{this.setState({playerindex:0},() => {console.log("After:"+this.state.playerindex);});}
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

But sometimes the index will increment while it should not, and causes this:

[image]

I think it might be the asynchronous behavior of `setState`, but I don't know how should I solve this problem.

If you have a solution or another way to achieve the expected behavior, please help!

Code here:

`App.js`: https://ghostbin.com/paste/e9wjg

`Attack.js`: https://ghostbin.com/paste/3zbwk

Comment: assign a conditional check like `<h4>You are: {this.props.targets && this.props.targets[this.props.playerindex] 
 && this.props.targets[this.props.playerindex].name}</h4>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri could you please explain this code? Also it stops the Error Massage, but sometimes the last player(Spud) is skipped.

Comment: In fact it's not the last player that is skipped but the next player after one player is killed

Comment: so what it is doing is checking if `this.props.targets` exits then checks if `this.props.targets[this.props.playerindex]` exists and then only returns the value else returns null. If its not rendering the last value then check what index you get

Comment: Thanks, I find the mistake after your remind

Answer (score 0):

I know what i am wrong:

when I am dropping a object, I should move the index back:

```
   if (life>damage){
        players[index2].life = life-damage;}
    else {players=players.filter(player => player.id !== id2);
          this.setState({playerindex:this.state.playerindex-1});}
```

This problem is solved, however please give me advice on this project if you like!

Comment: check this when you use setState https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492678/when-does-reacts-setstate-change-the-state/44493095#44493095